# Hi can someone help me translate these two signatures please! Thanks

Tags: translation, names

Trying to translate two watercolor paintings signatures I am having a hard time searching myself

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The right one wrote 春 (Spring)

The left one wrote 秋 (Autumn)

The seal on both paintings read 朱慧 (Zhū huì) -- the artist's name

[image]

[image]

[朱](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%9C%B1)

[慧](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%85%A7)